# How to create an APFS-formated volume on an external drive using Terminal

Tags: command-line, apfs

I want to create a case-sensitive encrypted APFS formatted Volume on my external drive using only the CLI. I had a look at `man diskutil` already but this doesn't seem to have all the details required. So I'm kind of stuck right now, any help appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109431/discussion-on-question-by-m0ll3art-how-to-create-an-apfs-formated-volume-on-an-e).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`newfs_apfs(8)`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/newfs_apfs/) to format a partition with a new APFS filesystem, i.e. to create a new APFS container. For example:

```
sudo newfs_apfs -e -v "My APFS Container" disk0s2
```

---

With `diskutil`, I find that just entering the `diskutil` command itself and reading the help that it outputs is more accessible than the manpage. You can do this for subcommands, too; `eraseVolume` is the subcommand you're interested in, and you can enter `diskutil eraseVolume` to get help on how to use this subcommand.

The `eraseVolume` subcommand will overwrite a partiton with a particular filesystem — it will use the relevant `newfs_*` command behind the scenes, thus serving as a general interface to all of the `newfs_*` commands — or leave the partition unformatted. `diskutil listFilesystems` will show you the valid filesystems you can specify. For example:

```
diskutil eraseVolume APFSX "My APFS Container" disk0s2
```

Alternatively, if you wish to reformat a partition that has an existing filesystem, keeping the same filesystem type and filesystem label / volume name, you can use the `reformat` subcommand instead. For example, if `disk0s2` is already a case-sensitive APFS container with the name `My APFS Container` that may already contain data or is broken, and you just want a clean slate, then the above `eraseVolume` command is equivalent to:

```
diskutil reformat disk0s2
```

*(Note that `diskutil` needn't be run with `sudo`.)*