# Creating APFS volume

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, apfs

I deleted my APFS container using the command:

`diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk2`

How can I create a container from my internal ssd?

Comment: Are you looking for how to boot to recovery and erase your startup disk? It’s hard to guess which disk is disk2 without more information.

Comment: According to `man diskutil` the container is replaced with a HFS volume when using `deleteContainer`. If you want to create a new APFS volume/container in its place check out previous questions and give the answer an upvote if it worked for you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393984/how-to-create-an-apfs-formated-volume-on-an-external-drive-using-terminal